Why does the quantum expectation in Bell's inequality have to take on the form of a quantum probability measure in Valter Moretti's book?
Valter Moretti, Fundamental Mathematical Structures of Quantum Theory Section 5.3.1 on Bell's inequality on p.204 as shown below  states in Equation (5.8) that we have to interpret the expectation $E_\mu(\mathbf{a,b})$ as an expectation value with respect to a quantum state operator or density matrix $T\in \mathscr S(\mathbb{S^2\otimes S^2})$
$$E_T(\mathbf{a,b})=\operatorname{tr}[T(\mathbf a\cdot\sigma\otimes \mathbf b\cdot\sigma)]$$
where $\sigma$ is the tuple of the 3 Pauli matrices.
What is the rationale for that, and this particular form? It resembles the form in Gleason's theorem which states that a quantum probability measure has to be $\operatorname{tr}(TP)$ for any orthogonal projector $P\in\mathscr L(H)$. However, since $\sigma$ involves only 3 matrices without the identity matrix, $\mathbf a\cdot\sigma$ is not an orthogonal projector and thus this expectation is not even a quantum probability measure. Then why does it have to take on the trace form with a density operator?

You can wait for his answer, since he's quite active on this site

The text refers to expectation values $tr(TA)$ of observables $A= a\cdot \sigma$ and not directly to  probabilities of their outcomes $tr(TP^{(A)}_\lambda)$.

Please don't use images/screenshots. Instead, type the relevant passage with MathJax.

Also, I think your question is unclear. Do you ask why in quantum mechanics expectation values are given as they are?

If $A$ is an observable (selfadjoint operator), for simplicity  in finite dimensions, we can expand it into its spectral decomposition
$$A= \sum_{\lambda \in \sigma(A)} \lambda P^{(A)}_\lambda\:.\tag{1}$$
If $T$ is a quantum state (density matrix) and $P$ and orthogonal projector, as you correctly stated, $tr(TP)$ is the probability that the elementary observable $P$ is true in the state $T$.
Coming back to (1), therein $P_\lambda^{(A)}$ is the elementary observable "the value of $A$ is $\lambda$".
According to these facts,  the expectation value of $A$ is
$$\langle A\rangle_T = \sum_{\lambda \in \sigma(A)}\lambda tr(TP^{(A)}_\lambda) 
= tr(TA)= tr(AT)\:,$$
where I used (1) and the linear property of the trace.
This proves that the notion of trace can be used also to compute expectation values and not only probabilities (as is the case in the statement of Gleason's theorem you mention).
The analysis of CHSH inequality I discussed in that book of mine relies upon the considerations above.
In the infinite dimensional case $$\langle A\rangle_T 
= tr(AT)$$ is still valid but it requires some hypotheses on $A$ if it is unbounded.Sect 4.5 of the book deals with these cases.

Wow, I got the author of the book to answer my question. Thank you, professor Valter Moretti. Embarrassingly, I skipped Sect 4.5 of your book previously. By the way, it would be even nicer if your book would show that $T=T_{\pm}$ maximizes $\operatorname{tr}[T(\mathbf a\cdot\sigma\otimes \mathbf b\cdot\sigma)]$.

Thanks...Maybe in the next edition I am premaring...
